# Wrapper class for executing database queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, wrapper

I have a wrapper class for executing database queries from an ASP.NET application. Please provide suggestions on how I can improve this class. It is working fine. Anyone can use this class in their ASP.NET application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class SPWrapper
{
    private string _ConnectionString = string.Empty;
    private Hashtable _ParamHT = new Hashtable();
    private QueryMode _QMode = QueryMode.ExecuteNonQuery;
    private string _SPName = string.Empty;
    private SqlCommand _SQLCmd;
    private string outputParams;
    private const string prfOut = "#";
    private SqlDataReader SPDataReader;
    private SqlParameter SPParam;
    private SqlTransaction SPTransaction;

    public SPWrapper()
    {
        this._ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MS_conn_string"].ToString();
    }

    public bool DBConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this._ConnectionString);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            ErrorLog.AddException(exception);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object ExecuteSP()
    {
        object obj3;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this._ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter;
            this._SQLCmd = new SqlCommand(this._SPName, connection);
            this._SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            string pName = string.Empty;
            bool flag = false;
            if ((this._ParamHT != null) && (this._ParamHT.Count != 0))
            {
                Hashtable pDataType = (Hashtable) this.GetPDataType();
                foreach (object obj2 in this._ParamHT.Keys)
                {
                    pName = obj2.ToString();
                    if (pName.Substring(0, 1) == "#")
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        pName = pName.Replace("#", "");
                    }
                    pName = "@" + pName;
                    this.SetParam(pName, pDataType[pName].ToString(), this._ParamHT[obj2].ToString(), flag);
                    flag = false;
                }
            }
            this._SQLCmd.Connection.Open();
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            if (this.Mode == QueryMode.ExecuteNonQuery)
            {
                this._SQLCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(this._SQLCmd);
                this.SetParamHT(adapter);
                adapter.Fill(dataSet);
                return dataSet;
            }
            if (this.Mode == QueryMode.ExecuteFunction)
            {
                SqlDataReader reader = this._SQLCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    return reader[0];
                }
                return 0;
            }
            this._SQLCmd.ExecuteScalar();
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(this._SQLCmd);
            this.SetParamHT(adapter);
            obj3 = true;
        }
        catch (SqlException exception)
        {
            ErrorLog.AddSqlException(exception);
            obj3 = false;
        }
        catch (Exception exception2)
        {
            ErrorLog.AddException(exception2);
            obj3 = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
                connection.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return obj3;
    }

    private bool ExistsInHT(string key)
    {
        return this._ParamHT.ContainsKey(key);
    }

    public object GetPDataType()
    {
        object obj2;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this._ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(this._ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("select dbo.syscolumns.name,type_name(dbo.syscolumns.xusertype) as dt, dbo.syscolumns.isoutparam from dbo.sysobjects inner join dbo.syscolumns on dbo.syscolumns.id = dbo.sysobjects.id where dbo.sysobjects.name = '" + this._SPName + "'", connection2);
            connection2.Open();
            selectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
            new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand).Fill(dataTable);
            connection2.Close();
            connection2.Dispose();
            if (dataTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    hashtable.Add(row[0], row[1]);
                }
            }
            obj2 = hashtable;
        }
        catch (SqlException exception)
        {
            ErrorLog.AddSqlException(exception);
            obj2 = null;
        }
        catch (Exception exception2)
        {
            ErrorLog.AddException(exception2);
            obj2 = null;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return obj2;
    }

    public void SetParam(string pName, string pDataType, string pValue, bool flag)
    {
        switch (pDataType.ToLower())
        {
            case "nvarchar":
                this.SPParam = this._SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0xfa0);
                if (flag)
                {
                    this.SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }
                if (pValue == "")
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = pValue;
                }
                break;

            case "varchar":
                this.SPParam = this._SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.VarChar, 0xfa0);
                if (flag)
                {
                    this.SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }
                if (pValue == "")
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = pValue;
                }
                break;

            case "text":
                this.SPParam = this._SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.Text);
                if (flag)
                {
                    this.SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }
                if (pValue == "")
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = pValue;
                }
                break;

            case "char":
                this.SPParam = this._SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.Char);
                if (flag)
                {
                    this.SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }
                if (pValue == "")
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = pValue;
                }
                break;

            case "int":
                this.SPParam = this._SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.Int);
                if (flag)
                {
                    this.SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }
                if (pValue == "")
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = pValue;
                }
                break;

            case "smallint":
                this.SPParam = this._SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.SmallInt);
                if (flag)
                {
                    this.SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }
                if (pValue == "")
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = pValue;
                }
                break;

            case "bigint":
                this.SPParam = this._SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.BigInt);
                if (flag)
                {
                    this.SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }
                if (pValue == "")
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = pValue;
                }
                break;

            case "numeric":
                this.SPParam = this._SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.Decimal, 0x26);
                if (flag)
                {
                    this.SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }
                if (pValue == "")
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(pValue);
                }
                break;

            case "money":
                this.SPParam = this._SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.Money);
                if (flag)
                {
                    this.SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }
                if (pValue == "")
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = pValue;
                }
                break;

            case "decimal":
                this.SPParam = this._SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.VarChar, 0x26);
                if (flag)
                {
                    this.SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }
                if (pValue == "")
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = pValue;
                }
                break;

            case "float":
                this.SPParam = this._SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.Float);
                if (flag)
                {
                    this.SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }
                if (pValue == "")
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = Convert.ToDouble(pValue);
                }
                break;

            case "datetime":
                this.SPParam = this._SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.DateTime);
                if (flag)
                {
                    this.SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }
                if (pValue == "")
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = pValue;
                }
                break;

            case "date":
                this.SPParam = this._SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.DateTime);
                if (flag)
                {
                    this.SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }
                if (pValue == "")
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = pValue;
                }
                break;

            case "bit":
                this.SPParam = this._SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.Bit);
                if (flag)
                {
                    this.SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }
                if (pValue == "")
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = pValue;
                }
                break;

            default:
                this.SPParam = this._SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.VarChar, 0xfa0);
                if (flag)
                {
                    this.SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                }
                if (pValue == "")
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.SPParam.Value = pValue;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void SetParamHT(SqlDataAdapter sda)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < sda.SelectCommand.Parameters.Count; i++)
            {
                string key = "#" + sda.SelectCommand.Parameters[i].ParameterName.Replace("@", "");
                if (this.ExistsInHT(key))
                {
                    this._ParamHT[key] = sda.SelectCommand.Parameters[i].Value.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            ErrorLog.AddException(exception);
        }
    }

    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ConnectionString;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ConnectionString = value;
        }
    }

    public QueryMode Mode
    {
        get
        {
            return this._QMode;
        }
        set
        {
            this._QMode = value;
        }
    }

    public Hashtable ParamHT
    {
        get
        {
            return this._ParamHT;
        }
        set
        {
            this._ParamHT = value;
        }
    }

    public string SPName
    {
        get
        {
            return this._SPName;
        }
        set
        {
            this._SPName = value;
        }
    }

    public enum QueryMode
    {
        ExecuteFunction = 5,
        ExecuteNonQuery = 1,
        ExecuteReader = 2,
        ExecuteScalar = 3,
        ExecuteXmlReader = 4
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You have 4 unused variables:

   ```
   private string outputParams;
   private const string prfOut = "#";
   private SqlDataReader SPDataReader;
   private SqlTransaction SPTransaction;
   ```
2. You can use object initializer in `ExecuteSP()` for your `_SQLCmd`:

   ```
   _SQLCmd = new SqlCommand(_SPName, connection) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure};
   ```
3. There are 2 places where you do:

> ```
> finally
> {
>     if (connection != null)
>     {
>         connection.Close();
>         connection.Dispose();
>     }
> }
> ```

The if statement here is redundant.

Moving on to your longest method - `SetParam`, most of your code here is redundant.

First this if statement is the same everywhere:

> ```
> if (flag)
> {
>      SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
> }
> ```

You can just move it to the bottom or the top.

Next this if statement is also the same everywhere:

```
if (pValue == "")
{
    SPParam.Value = DBNull.Value;
}
```

But there is an else connected to it so you cant just move out this one without worrying about the else. What you can do instead is make a helper variable to save the correct value upon entering the `case:` and than move the whole if/else outside the `switch`.

Lastly I'm not sure if this is possible in your case but if you can convert `pDataType` from `string` to `SqlDbType` your switch case will be just a few lines. Without that it looks like this:

```
public void SetParam(string pName, string pDataType, string pValue, bool flag)
{
    object paramValue = pValue;
    switch (pDataType.ToLower())
    {
        case "nvarchar":
            SPParam = _SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.NVarChar, 0xfa0);
            break;
        case "varchar":
            SPParam = _SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.VarChar, 0xfa0);
            break;
        case "text":
            SPParam = _SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.Text);
            break;
        case "char":
            SPParam = _SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.Char);
            break;
        case "int":
            SPParam = _SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.Int);
            break;
        case "smallint":
            SPParam = _SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.SmallInt);
            break;
        case "bigint":
            SPParam = _SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.BigInt);
            break;
        case "numeric":
            SPParam = _SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.Decimal, 0x26);
            paramValue = Convert.ToDecimal(pValue);
            break;
        case "money":
            SPParam = _SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.Money);
            break;
        case "decimal":
            SPParam = _SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.VarChar, 0x26);
            break;
        case "float":
            SPParam = _SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.Float);
            paramValue = Convert.ToDouble(pValue);
            break;
        case "datetime":
            SPParam = _SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.DateTime);
            break;
        case "date":
            SPParam = _SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.DateTime);
            break;
        case "bit":
            SPParam = _SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.Bit);
            break;
        default:
            SPParam = _SQLCmd.Parameters.Add(pName, SqlDbType.VarChar, 0xfa0);
            break;
    }
    if (flag)
    {
        SPParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    }
    SPParam.Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(pValue) ? DBNull.Value : paramValue;
}
```

You can get rid of some of your private variables and shorten your properties by using *auto properties*:

> ```
> private string _ConnectionString = string.Empty;
> private Hashtable _ParamHT = new Hashtable();
> private QueryMode _QMode = QueryMode.ExecuteNonQuery;
> private string _SPName = string.Empty;
>
> public string ConnectionString
> {
>     get { return _ConnectionString; }
>     set { _ConnectionString = value; }
> }
>
> public QueryMode Mode
> {
>     get { return _QMode; }
>     set { _QMode = value; }
> }
>
> public Hashtable ParamHT
> {
>     get { return _ParamHT; }
>     set { _ParamHT = value; }
> }
>
> public string SPName
> {
>     get { return _SPName; }
>     set { _SPName = value; }
> }
> ```

Can be shorten to:

```
public string ConnectionString { get; set; } = string.Empty;

public QueryMode Mode { get; set; } = QueryMode.ExecuteNonQuery;

public Hashtable ParamHT { get; set; } = new Hashtable();

public string SPName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

Comment: If you parsed the `pDataType` you could get rid of the entire `switch` ;-) but I wonder why OP is using strings for it at all and not just the enum.

Comment: @t3chb0t Well in case he obtains the data from somewhere else not manually passing it, it makes *some* sense to be a string but still, it should simply be the enum type.